# How do I split a vim Window using python?

Tags: vimscript-python

The vim documentation of the [Python interface to vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/if_pyth.html) mentions:

> The height attribute is writable only if the screen is split horizontally.
>   The width attribute is writable only if the screen is split vertically.

It seems to assume that a split has already been made. But I did not find on that page is how to split a window using python.

So my question is how does one split a python window horizontally/vertically using python?

Answer (score 1):

`:py vim.command("sp")` did it for me.

Comment: didn't work in python 8.1. I guess it need 8.2 or newer